# Sublime snippet with params on tabTrigger

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

For example somewhere inside .html file i type:

```
temp:some-id
```

And expect my snippet creation magic to return this with the specified "some-id" :

```
<script type="text/template" id="some-id"></script>
```

So i need a way to trigger some text and pass through some arguments to the snippet creation file so when the triggering happens I can assign that arguments to some tab-placeholder inside .sublime-snippet. Any ideas?

P.S. im using sublime text 2, if it matters.

Comment: Why not use the zen coding package?

Comment: Also, if you want to make the snippet yourself take a look at how zen coding is done with python scripts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the variable `$TM_CURRENT_WORD`, you can look into this [page](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html) for more detail

However when testing this I noticed that if I have the snippet:

```
Hello, $TM_CURRENT_WORD
```

with the trigger `hello:` with my desired word directly after `:` something like `hello:user` i must have `user` highlighted if I want a tab to trigger my snippet so it should work just as fine with the variable `$SELECTION` in this case.

Hope this helps.