# How can I write "dynamic" snippets in sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Say my code is like this:

```
datatype type_name =
  | a of ()
  | b of ()
  ...  // more
```

Is it possible for me to generate a `| ${place_holder} of ()` pair each time I press tab?

My current snippet is:

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
datatype ${1:type_name} =
  | ${2} of (${3})
  ${4}
]]></content>
  <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
  <tabTrigger>dat</tabTrigger>
  <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
  <scope>source.ats</scope>
</snippet>
```

But as you see, then the user hit's tab the 4th time, I can't generate another `| of ()` pair.

Comment: Why not assign `| ${1} of (${2})` to a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an (inelegant) hack using substitutions. Press the spacebar as many times as you wish when the fourth field is selected.

```
<snippet>
  <content><![CDATA[
datatype ${1:type_name} =
  | ${2} of (${3})
  ${4:(spacebar)}
  ${4/ /| a of ()\n\t/g}
]]></content>
  <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
  <tabTrigger>dat</tabTrigger>
  <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
  <scope>source.python</scope>
</snippet>
```

A more elegant solution may be possible via the $PARAM environmental variable: you may be able to pass an integer to insertSnippet and use that to construct the replacement text via the substitution example shown above. Documentation is [here](http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/extensibility/snippets.html) but unfortunately gives little info on $PARAM. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056617/sublime-snippet-with-params-on-tabtrigger) also gives a helpful example on how to pass a parameter.